# $L^{\infty}$ translation continuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\tau_h$ denote the the translation of $f$ by $h$, i.e $\tau_h f(x) = f(x+h)$ . Let $f \in L^\infty$, then $f$ is not continuous under $h$, i.e $\tau_h f$ does not converge to $f$ in the $\infty$ norm as $h$ tends to $0$.

My proof: Consider the function given by $2x\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \cos (1/x)$ at $x \neq 0$, and $0$ at $x = 0$, restricted to the interval $[-1,1]$. Then, we see that this function is bounded everywhere, but the translation operator is not continuous. Indeed, no matter how small we take $h$, we have at $x = 0$ that $\|f_h - f\|_\infty = \|f_h\|_\infty$ oscillates rapidly between $1$, $-1$, and thus we cannot have convergence under the supremum norm, as it will always bre greater than or equal to $2 -\epsilon$ for some point.

Comment: Did you consider first $f = \mathbf{1}_{[0, 1]}$ (the indicator function of the interval $[0, 1]$)? (I did not downvote the question.)

Comment: Wow. I feel silly

Comment: My instructor, many years past now, used to make us feel silly by giving us counterexamples with the zero or identity matrix (we would always complicate the results too much).

Comment: Does this counterexample (the indicator function) hold because at $x=0$ you will get that the norm will never be zero, no matter how small you take $h$ (i.e, the norm will always have value 1 at the point x=0?)

Comment: In general, if you translate by nonzero (but arbitrarily small $h$), there will be a point where $\tau_hf(x) - f(x) = 1$, meaning that thee l infinity difference is $1$. This doesn't happen in $L^p$ (non infinity spaces) because the small measure of this set takes care of the huge jump.